# ODBC connection error when opening connection from second website PHP file

Tags: php, odbc

I have an website that is pulling bottling calendar information through and ODBC connection.  The first time I open the connection in my main file it works fine.  However, in that file I have some jquery that posts to another file that also uses the ODBC connection.  However, the ODBC connection always fails in the second file.

Note, if I put the second ODBC connection at the bottom of the first file it works.  I thought maybe that I needed to close the first connection, but that seems to have no bearing on whether it works or not.

for example, I tried odbc_close();  or odbc_close($conn);

Also, if run the other file separetly (ie open it on it's own in it's own window) the connection opens fine.

Any ideas?

http://hq.terravant.com/calendar/calendar.php

```
    $conn = odbcConnect();
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM Master_Schedule Master_Schedule_0  ");
    $result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

    $cases = (odbc_result($result, 'Quantity'))/12;
    $productDesc = odbc_result($result, 'ProdDesc');
    $odbcDate = odbc_result($result, 'Date');
    $ProdNo = odbc_result($result, 'ProdNo');




    ?>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>On Hand</th>
            <th>Variance</th>
        </thead>
            <tr> <td>Date</td>          <td>    <?php echo $odbcDate; ?>     </td> <td>  </tr>
            <tr> <td>Product ID</td>    <td>    <?php echo $ProdNo ?>    </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>Product Desc</td>  <td>    <?php echo $productDesc ?>   </td> <td> <?php echo $cases ?> </td> </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the JQuery $.post functionality I was using to call the other file was in inside of a loop, and it was causing the odbc_database to be called to many times.  Probably using up our number of licenses I'm assuming.

Which would explain why it was fine earlier when I was using it for an MySQL database, no restriction on number of licenses.

Sorry for such a dumb mistake on my part.